# wrong format of DatePicker - windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, datepicker

I added ValueStringFormat but this only changed format of control:

```
<toolkit:DatePicker  Value="{Binding DOB,Mode=TwoWay}" S ValueStringFormat="{}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"/>
```

DatePickerPage still show date as MM/dd/YYYY. How can I fixed it?

Comment: Because it is using the format that phone is using. You need to override culture info or change default language of your app in your project.

Comment: Works! Thank you very much!